# App works fine on Debug but not on AdHoc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, adhoc

I have an App that works perfectly on Debug (device and simulator) but once I archive it for AdHoc it just crashes.

Even with the Distribution provision files selected y clic play and works fine.

Now if I make an .ipa through AdHoc... it loads and crashes... 1seg... not even open.

I guess maybe something is wrong, but how on earth I can find the bug if there's any? I don't have any log message and it's a big big App.

Any idea?

Thanks.

---

```
  By the way, this is what I get:

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38af35d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x39a0d4e8 CFURLCopyScheme + 144
2   CoreGraphics                    0x318e6e28 CGDataProviderCreateWithURL + 44
3   CoreGraphics                    0x318ffc5c CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL + 4
4   READERSoft                      0x000e10f0 CGPDFDocumentCreateX (CGPDFDocument.m:42)
5   READERSoft                      0x000aeab4 -[ContentViewController viewDidLoad] (ContentViewController.m:56)
6   UIKit                           0x332ce544 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
7   UIKit                           0x3330ed2c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 60
8   UIKit                           0x3330aac8 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 360
9   UIKit                           0x3334c19c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
10  READERSoft                      0x000b618a -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:44)
11  UIKit                           0x3330fa74 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
12  UIKit                           0x3330f5f8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
13  UIKit                           0x33307806 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
14  UIKit                           0x332afcea -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
15  UIKit                           0x332af778 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
16  UIKit                           0x332af1ba _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
17  GraphicsServices                0x39b435f4 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
18  GraphicsServices                0x39b43222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
19  CoreFoundation                  0x39a743e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
20  CoreFoundation                  0x39a74386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
21  CoreFoundation                  0x39a7320a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
22  CoreFoundation                  0x399e6238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation                  0x399e60c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  UIKit                           0x33306440 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
25  UIKit                           0x3330328c UIApplicationMain + 1116
26  READERSoft                      0x000b5f5a main (main.m:9)
27  READERSoft                      0x000ae89c start + 36
```

Comment: @jackslash You got it...

Comment: I had a look and dont have much further insight. The question is better with a crash log so i upvoted it.

Comment: I got same issue, Please chec this log: